# How to design a table in MS Word that wraps text around a cell in a corner?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, text-formatting

Here's what I want to achieve:

**Screenshot 1: Desired output**
[image: Screen shot 1: Desired output]

In other words, I want the whole grey area to be one cell, the content of which wraps itself around the cell with white background. While in the above screenshot 1 it looks like this is the case, I cheated because apparently a cell can't have a shape other than rectangular, see screenshot 2 below:

**Screenshot 2: Actual output**
[image]

Are there any workarounds to this problem? I've tried using a text box as a replacement for the white cell but haven't been able 
 to position it correctly (i.e. exactly like the white cell).

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Not really. You can use a text box (it is hard as you describe) but that won't allow text to wrap correctly ... if you edit the text you have to wrap it yourself.